# ARM v7-M Instruction Set Decoding Function

Tags: compiler-construction, arm, instruction-set, objdump

Is there any instruction decoder for the ARM v7-M Instruction Set, that I can just give it an opcode as parameter and return me with the corresponding instruction type?

For example: `MOV Rd, <op2>`

has four different versions depending on the `<op2>`.

1. A simple register specifier, for example *Rm*.
2. An immediate shifted register, for example *Rm, LSL #4*.
3. A register shifted register, for example *Rm, LSL Rs*.
4. An immediate value, for example *#0xE000E000*.

I want to know which of this version it is from the [opcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) of the instruction?

---

Editors note: [opcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) means the actual 'hex' instruction or machine encoding.  The question is about the assembler [*mnemonic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).  On many CPUs a leading *mnemonic* may map to different *opcodes* (or machine instructions) depending on the arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called a disassembler.  Put the op code in an assembly file, build it, and then disassemble it.

```
$ cat in.s
    .syntax unified
    .align  2
    .code   16
    .globl  _foo
    .thumb_func _foo
_foo:
    .short  0x4615
    .long   0x43e0e92d

$ clang -arch armv7m -c in.s
$ otool -arch armv7m -tv in.o
in.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_foo:
00000000        4615    mov r5, r2
00000002    e92d43e0    push.w  {r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, lr}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not what I am looking for. For example: MOV Rd, <op2> has four different versions depending on the <op2>. a) A simple register specifier, for example Rm.
b) An immediate shifted register, for example Rm, LSL #4.
c) A register shifted register, for example Rm, LSL Rs.
d) An immediate value, for example #0xE000E000. I want to know which of this version it is without need to dissemble the file and parse it to figure out. If there is no tool, I guess I will need to parse it and figure out then

Comment: @kkk This advice still applies.  Instead of using `.short` and `.long`, write your actual code and use `objdump` to see the opcode chosen by the assembler.  Another method is to generate a listing file.  For your `mov` example, the op-code chosen will be apparent.  An assembler will not choose an `lsl #0` option (if it exists) for instance.  Forensics may use this choice to determine what compiler/assembler was used for something.  Some instructions are ambiguous or have multiple encodings.  A  *mnemonic* may even be a *pseudo-instruction* and map to multiple op-codes.